# Static Table View - UITextField hidden by Keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

Maybe this is a recurrent question, but I got stuck with this issue and some iOS concepts. I have a **ViewController** with a **Static Table View**, **Three Sections** and some **Rows** on Each Section. Inside the rows I have UITextFields. What I’m trying to do is preventing the keyboard to hide my bottom screen UI Text Fields. I’ve just tried an apple solution from [Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), but since I'm not getting the concept behind the scroll view attached to a static table view, I couldn't implement the idea into my project. Do you guys recommend anyplace to learn it? Sorry if couldn't explain what I'm trying to do. I'm a little lost.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Marcos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to do something similar, here's my code, hopefully it helps you.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.bounds;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    CGRect activeRect = [activeTextField convertRect:activeTextField.frame toView:self];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeRect.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeRect.origin.y-kbSize.height+10);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = nil;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

Also, make sure to set your notification observers when loading your view, like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Just define activeTextField as a UITextField and make sure everything you want to move is contained in your scrollView (in your case you can probably change your viewController to a scrollView). Also, make sure your scrollView's contentSize is at least self.bounds.size.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for fast replying. Is your scrollView a tableView? And what about self.bounds? What is self? My class self is a UITableViewController.

Comment: My scrollView is a UIScrollView. This scrollView should actually be above your UITableView, but will probably be contained in a UIViewController itself, making your self a UIViewController and self.view.bounds would be what you should set your scrollView's contentSize to.

Comment: yes I got it and it's working in portrait mode. since I rotate to landscape it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: You'll probably have to reset your scrollView's content size when you rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this in my application - Stakenborg's answer got me 80% there, but there were a couple of additional refinements I added to work with TableViews specifically.

The main bits are that:

- TableViews already have insets, so we need to add or subtract from those.
- I also want to scroll so that the cell I'm editing is in a good place to be seen.

The second part requires a little bit of indirection - the text fields belong to my custom cells, so I need to respond to the BeginEditing message there by sending a message to the UITableViewController.

Here's how it all comes together.  In the UITableViewController:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *editCellIndexPath;
@property (nonatomic) bool keyboardShowing;

//....

- (void)setEditRow:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    self.editCellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (self.keyboardShowing)
    {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.editCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:true];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    CGSize kbSize = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = [self.tableView contentInset];
    edgeInsets.bottom += kbSize.height;
    UIEdgeInsets scrollInsets = [self.tableView scrollIndicatorInsets];
    scrollInsets.bottom += kbSize.height;

    self.keyboardShowing = true;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self.tableView setContentInset:edgeInsets];
        [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:scrollInsets];
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    CGSize kbSize = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[[sender userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = [self.tableView contentInset];
    edgeInsets.bottom -= kbSize.height;
    UIEdgeInsets scrollInsets = [self.tableView scrollIndicatorInsets];
    scrollInsets.bottom -= kbSize.height;

    self.keyboardShowing = false;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        [self.tableView setContentInset:edgeInsets];
        [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:scrollInsets];
    }];
}
```

Then I have a weak property for the owningController in each of my custom UITableViewCells, and let the controller know when my cell is being text-edited.  I use a TextView in one, and TextFields in another row, so I use these methods:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    MyCustomTableController *itemControl = (MyCustomTableController *)self.owningController;
    [itemControl setEditRow:self];
}
```

and

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    MyCustomTableController *itemControl = (MyCustomTableController *)self.owningController;
    [itemControl setEditRow:self];
}
```

So far, this is working very well.